# Linux memory usage is much larger than the sum of memory used by all applications?

Tags: linux, memory, operating-system

I am using "free -m -t " command to monitor my linux system and get

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached

Mem:         64334      64120        213          0        701      33216

-/+ buffers/cache:      30202      34131

Swap:          996          0        996

Total:       65330      64120       1209
```

it means 30GB of physical memory is used by user processes.

but when using top command and sort by memory usage, only 3~4GB of memory is used by all the application processes.

Why does this inconsistency happen?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, the amount of memory that top shows as used includes cold memory from older processes that are not running anymore. This is due to the fact that in case of a restart of said process, the required data may still be in memory, enabling the system to start the process faster and more efficiently instead or always reloading the data from disk.

or, in short, linux generally frees cold data in memory as late as possible.

Hope that clears it up :)

Comment: thanks, any command or tools to see who these 'dark' memory belongs to?

Comment: it belongs to nobody. only the system knows where it's from. most likely it's only data pages representing slices of your hard disk, containing program binary. nothing to worry about.

Comment: IMHO, data pages mapping to the disk is only included in the first line of free command, the 'used memroy' in second line has excluded it. is that right?

Comment: @Shawn unfortunately, I'm not that familiar with free. but I bet there's a manpage...?