# Report of memory used doesn't add up. Is Windows lying?

Tags: windows, memory, operating-system

While running a very intensive script in cmd, I looked at the memory used in Task Manager, and something struck me as curious:
[screenshot of task manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwPaP.png)

(collage of the entire column if you're interested, but it's not that relevant: https://imgur.com/a/Y8x59tv)

Summing up the values in the entire Memory column results in 12,129.6 MB, or 12.1296 GB, of memory that Windows is using. Of course, this isn't an exact measurement, since memory usage is always fluctuating, and I may have skipped/double counted some processes. But it's a close enough measurement - once we get out of the the top 10 memory hogs, each process only uses ~5 MB or less. Inconsequential.

Windows claims this is 96% of my memory. However, a quick look at my PC Info settings show that my laptop has 16 GB (15.7 GB usable) of memory. Last I checked, ~12 is not 96% of ~16.

Why is this measurement inaccurate? Is Windows doing the math wrong, or lying, or leaving out some memory-using process? I would think that core OS stuff would still be listed as a service in Task Manager, or just as a generic "other misc." category.

Note: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489472/linux-memory-usage-is-much-larger-than-the-sum-of-memory-used-by-all-application) isn't a duplicate, since it is a different OS and talking about underestimating memory used, not overestimating.